# how to include firebase sdk on an ios project without the -objc flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, delphi, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to include in my project facebook sdk and firebase sdk. The problem is that firebase sdk require to set the -objC flag, but when i do so then the Facebook sdk will not compile anymore. ([compiling facebook sdk with -ObjC option result with framework not found Bolts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794460/compiling-facebook-sdk-with-objc-option-result-with-framework-not-found-bolts))

So is their anyway to include the firebase SDK without the -Objc flag? without this flag i receive the error : **selector not recognized**

I try to replace the -objc flag by **-force_load** like this :

```
-force_load C:\lib\firebase\FirebaseCore.framework\FirebaseCore 
-force_load C:\lib\firebase\FirebaseAnalytics.framework\FirebaseAnalytics 
-force_load C:\lib\firebase\FirebaseInstanceID.framework\FirebaseInstanceID 
-force_load C:\lib\firebase\FirebaseMessaging.framework\FirebaseMessaging 
-force_load C:\lib\firebase\GoogleToolboxForMac.framework\GoogleToolboxForMac 
-force_load C:\lib\firebase\Protobuf.framework\Protobuf
```

However if i don't have anymore the `selector not recognized` error i have now my app crashing at startup just after receiving the message

```
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Unable to get short BSD proc info for 2551: No such process
```

What can i do ? Also note that i m not under xcode, i m under Delphi

Comment: With Xcode it takes 2 lines in your podfile to include FCM to your project.
Don't know about Delphi

Comment: in delphi no way to use podfile as i know :(